# Codeigniter Issues with inserting arrays

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, codeigniter

This could ultimately prove not to be the issue, but I'll give a bit of background on the situation.

I've (attempted) to create a return goods authorization system for the business I work for. All internal testing seemed to indicated that the system was working as intended and that all bugs were fixed. My error log was empty and my javascript console showed nothing out of the ordinary.

On *Certain Cases* which I'm imagining is due to an outdated browser ( though I'm skeptical, because it seems to be a server side issue ) the 'returned' products are not being inserted into my database.

On submit, I'm gathering and putting in the user's contact information into a table in my database -- This works great and without issue.

Once I've gotten that information in, I'm then running a **foreach** loop on fields that have arrays for names.

```
foreach( $this -> input -> post('po_number') as $number => $value ){

    $ponum   = $this -> input -> post('po_number');
    $innum   = $this -> input -> post('inv_number');
    $qty     = $this -> input -> post('quantity');
    $panum   = $this -> input -> post('part_number');
    $desc    = $this -> input -> post('description');
    $reason = $this -> input -> post('reason');

    $insert_requests = array(
        'rga_id'        => $rga_no,
        'po_number'     => $ponum[$number],
        'inv_number'    => $innum[$number],
        'quantity'      => $qty[$number],
        'part_number'   => $panum[$number],
        'description'   => $desc[$number],
        'reason'        => $reason[$number]
    );

    if( $insert_requests['po_number'] != 0){

        $input = $this->db->insert('new_rga_returns', $insert_requests);
    }
}
```

So this is doing what I mentioned above. Each one of those "$this->input->post" 's is a field I have, which can be added via javascript / jQuery. Initially there's one row of inputs with the ability to add more as you see fit.

However, not even one row per "RGA" has been being sent through.

The most frustrating part is that ( as mentioned above ) whenever someone in the office inputs a request, it works (running win7 chrome V41). I've also tested on IE10 and the latest version of FireFox and everything runs fine. (Can't download older browsers due to compatibility)

We've had one person make a 'return' on their mac and that seemed to break it as well.

As far as I can tell, it seems to be an issue with different machines / browsers / operating systems handling the input arrays differently...

Comment: You can download older versions of IE from modern.ie for testing purposes.

Comment: The browser has no baring on how the array is constructed in the PHP.  What is probably happening is that the parameters are not getting sent on the browsers you are having a problem with.  Is this coming through a form or ajax request?   If it is the later, perhaps something is not working in the JavaScript for those browsers.

Comment: PHP runs on the server...  if the posted data is the same, PHP cares nothing about the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing the

```
$insert_requests['po_number'] != 0
```

from my **if** statement and simply replaced it with

```
if( $insert_requests ) { ... }
```

Stupid thing to put in there in the first place on my behalf. Thanks to those who commented.

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION**

Should have been checking if the insert request even existed instead of seeing if it was equal to something or not.

Comment: What do you think this has to do with the browser?

Comment: The people filling out the lines that weren't being pushed through were using older versions of browsers on windows XP or Vista. Everyone that was able to send in a successful order was using (relatively) new browsers on windows 7 or above.

I was skeptical of it at first because I knew it had to be a server side issue, which is why I was confused. Cleared it up though.

Comment: I understand you cleared it up.  I was just hoping for a logical explanation.

Comment: There wasn't one. At that point I had been trying to debug the problem for about an hour and a half with everything I tried ending up either making issues worse or not working at all, so I was frustrated and trying to consider all possible issues. The application is quite ajax/jquery heavy and thought something may have gone wrong in one of my calls. But I even went as far as to rewrite most of it and there were no issues, so the thought was misguided.

Comment: Ok, just an FYI... StackOverflow is about maintaining a quality repository of Q&A that helps future readers.  My comment/question is only meant to serve that end.  While your answer solves your issue, without knowing what the root cause, it's unlikely that it would ever help anyone else.